# LIKE restriction from the Hibernate Criteria API

Tags: hibernate, criteria

I am trying to query PostgreSQL database using Hibernate's restriction criterion [`like()`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#like-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) with a partial keyword:

```
Criterion c1 = Restrictions.like("stateName", "Virg*");
cri.add(c1);

return cri.list();
```

It doesn't return anything but `Restrictions.like("stateName", "Virginia");` returns the correct record. How do I use partial *like* restrictions in Hibernate?

EDIT:
Got it working by doing something like this:

```
public static List<Object> createQueryStringByRegex(Criteria cri, Parameters p) {
    String value = (String) p.value;
    if (value.contains("*")) {
        value = value.replace("*", "%");
    } else {
        value += "%";
    }
    // System.out.println("Value: "+value);
    Criterion c1 = Restrictions.ilike(p.property, value);
    cri.add(c1);

    return cri.list();

}
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Use the enum [MatchMode](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/MatchMode.html) to help you with it:

```
Criterion c1 = Restrictions.like("stateName", "Virg", MatchMode.START);
```

Don't use any special character, like *. And if you want a case-insensitive like, use [ilike](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#ilike%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20org.hibernate.criterion.MatchMode%29).

Comment: doesn't use of `ilike` depend on if the underlying DB supports it? I.e. Postgres supports ilike but others may not?

Comment: I believe not, at least there isn't anything about it in the documentation. Probably Hibernate by itself provides this feature.

Comment: For the sake of his question, shouldnt the `MatchMode` be `MatchMode.START`?

Comment: @Juliano actually MatchMode.START is right because it tells hibernate to match from the beginning. That is if you translate this to mysql implementation it becomes 'SELECT * FROM <table> where <column> LIKE "parameter%"

Answer (score 11):

The restriction should use the percent symbol.

```
Criterion c1 = Restrictions.like("stateName", "Virg%");
```

Comment: Youre way more flexible in which database to choose or migrate to in the future if you use the `MatchMode` as suggested by Juliano's answer.

Comment: Just use MatchMode, this is defeating one of the reason to use the API in the first place, which is for your code to be database agnostic!

Answer (score 1):

```
##Use MatchMode.ANYWHERE##
DetachedCriteria crit = DetachedCriteria.forClass(MyClass.class);
 crit.add(Restrictions.like("prop1", "matchValue", MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
 return getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(crit);
```

it's equivalent to:

```
select * 
    from Table_Name 
    where prop1 like "%matchValue%";
```