# Hibernate findByExample with 'like'like behaviour on not null (string?) fields from the example

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate

I'm using hibernate 4 and Spring 3. As the long title says, I need to create a method like this

```
public list<MyObject> findByExample(MyObject exampleInstance){
    Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(MyObject.class);
    Example example = Example.create(exampleInstance);
    crit.add(example);
    return crit.list();
}
```

but making Hibernate compare the example with the value of the field with a `like` statement. Something like a `findByLikeExample(MyObject exampleInstance)`

**Example:**

MyObject is mapped to a table `myobject` with the columns `name` and `description`, therefore it looks like this

```
@Entity
public class MyObject{

    private String name;
    private String description;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

The table `myobject` contains two lines

```
+--------------------------------------------+
|name         | description                  |
+--------------------------------------------+
|test line    | This is a test line          |
|Second line  | This is the second test line |
+--------------------------------------------+
```

I would like this code

```
MyObject exampleInstance= new MyObject();
exampleInstance.setName("line");
return findByLikeExample(exampleInstance);
```

to return all the lines in the table (two distinct `MyObject` entities)

**Important note**: `MyObject` in this case can be a type parameter, so I don't know the fields in advance.
I know it can be achieved by cycling on all the fields of my `exampleInstance` (with reflection) and adding a `Restriction.like` to `crit` for the value contained in my field (if not null and if it supports a like statement), but I'd rather do this without reflection. Is it possible?

Comment: This link may help you using `Parameters` with `property` and `value` passing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14264513/hibernate-restriction-like

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately this would require me to use reflection to iterate throug field names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Hibernate 4 supports 'like' in *Query By Example* with `"%"`

You just need to enable the feature by calling `.enableLike()` while creating the `Example example` in your DAO *findByExample* method.

**Example code (Not tested !) :**

A *findByExample* method which allow 'like' in a **generic DAO** implementation :

```
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
public List<E> findByExample(final E exampleEntity) {
    final Example example = Example.create(exampleEntity).excludeZeroes().enableLike();
    return this.session.createCriteria(this.domainClass).add(example).list();
}
```

Usage in a **Service layer** :

```
MyObject exampleInstance= new MyObject();
exampleInstance.setName("%line%");
Collection<MyObject> results = myObjectDao.findByExample(exampleInstance);
```

(In your example `exampleInstance.setName("%line");` would match too)

Comment: Tested, doesn't work... Maybe I'm doing something wrong, i'll post my code asap

Comment: My bad.. I forgot the main point <code>.enableLike()</code>. I edited my answer.

Comment: Good! it works, many thanks! I sought a lot but couldn't find any reference about it... Probably I should start studying seriously Hibernate.